# pandas filter rows by two column values with case insenstive

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe as follows:

```
Last Known Date ConfigredValue  ReferenceValue
0   24-Jun-17   False   FALSE
1   25-Jun-17   FALSE   FALSE
2   26-Jun-17   TRUE    FALSE
3   27-Jun-17   FALSE   FALSE
4   28-Jun-17   false   FALSE
```

If I do the following command

**`df=df[df['ConfigredValue']!=dfs['ReferenceValue']]`**

then I get as below

```
0   24-Jun-17   False   FALSE
2   26-Jun-17   TRUE    FALSE
4   28-Jun-17   false   FALSE
```

But I want the filter with case insensitive (case=False)

I want following output:

```
2   26-Jun-17   TRUE    FALSE
```

Please suggest, how to get filtered case insensitive data(case=false)

Comment: `replace` then `filter`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Option 1: convert to lowercase or to uppercase and compare

The simplest is to convert the two columns to lower (or to upper) before checking for equality:

```
df=df[df['ConfigredValue'].str.lower()!=df['ReferenceValue'].str.lower()]
```

or

```
df=df[df['ConfigredValue'].str.upper()!=df['ReferenceValue'].str.upper()]
```

output:

```
Out: 
  Last Known Date ConfigredValue ReferenceValue
2    2  26-Jun-17           TRUE          FALSE
```

---

#### Option 2: Compare the lengths

In this particuler case, you can simply compare the lengths of TRUE and True, they are the same wether the string is upper or lower case:

```
df[df['ConfigredValue'].str.len()!=df['ReferenceValue'].str.len()]
```

output:

```
Out: 
  Last Known Date ConfigredValue ReferenceValue
2    2  26-Jun-17           TRUE          FALSE
```

---

#### Option 3: Vectorized title

`str.title()` was also suggested in @0p3n5ourcE answer, here's a vectorized version of it:

```
df[df['ConfigredValue'].str.title()!=df['ReferenceValue'].str.title()]
```

---

#### Execution time

Benchmarking the speed shows that `str.len()` is a bit faster

```
In [35]: timeit df[df['ConfigredValue'].str.lower()!=df['ReferenceValue'].str.lower()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 496 µs per loop

In [36]: timeit df[df['ConfigredValue'].str.upper()!=df['ReferenceValue'].str.upper()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 496 µs per loop

In [37]: timeit df[df['ConfigredValue'].str.title()!=df['ReferenceValue'].str.title()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 495 µs per loop

In [38]: timeit df[df['ConfigredValue'].str.len()!=df['ReferenceValue'].str.len()]
1000 loops, best of 3: 479 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Better replace existing false with 'FALSE' with `case = False` parameter ie

```
df['ConfigredValue'] = df['ConfigredValue'].str.replace('false','FALSE',case=False)

df=df[df['ConfigredValue']!=df['ReferenceValue']]
```

Output:

```
   Last Known_Date ConfigredValue ReferenceValue
2     2  26-Jun-17           TRUE          FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the columns hold `boolean` values, if it is not a problem converting the columns to `boolean` datatype then, following can work too (*where `.title()` is used to change first character of string to uppercase e.g. FALSE to False, or true to True which can be used to convert then to corresponding boolean value*):

```
df['ConfigredValue'] = df['ConfigredValue'].apply(lambda row: eval(row.title()))
df['ReferenceValue'] = df['ReferenceValue'].apply(lambda row: eval(row.title()))
```

Then, using same comparison as above:

```
df[df['ConfigredValue'] != df['ReferenceValue']]
```

Output:

```
    Last Known Date  ConfigredValue  ReferenceValue
2       26-Jun-17            True           False
```

Or, simply using title only similar to uppercase or lowercase:

```
df[df['ConfigredValue'].str.title() !=df['ReferenceValue'].str.title()]
```

Comment: I'm glad someone used `str.title`

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks, but I am not sure if changing the datatype to boolean would be better practice.

Comment: Agreed.  Ultimately, it's up to OP.  You provided an option that you can follow up with `literal_eval` from the `ast` package to change to `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

**Outside the box**
`pandas.read_csv` reads all of these in as boolean.  You can dump to csv and read it in again.  Then you can use `pd.DataFrame.query`

```
pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO(df.to_csv(index=False))).query(
    'ConfigredValue != ReferenceValue')

  Last Known Date  ConfigredValue  ReferenceValue
2       26-Jun-17            True           False
```